# dockerode stream "data" listener echoes write data

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerode

I'm trying to figure out why dockerode stream directs all data written to the stream directly to the output of the stream.

This is how I create the container, I call the `.write()` method on the `this.stream` object.

```js
        this.container = await this.dockerConnection.createContainer({
            Image: this.image,
            Tty: true,
            Cmd: cmd,
            HostConfig: {
                NetworkMode: "none",
                Binds: [this.mountPath + ":/home/appuser/workdir"],
            },
            OpenStdin: true,
            StdinOnce: false,
            AutoRemove: true,
        });

        this.stream = await this.container.attach({
            stream: true,
            stdin: true,
            stdout: true,
            stderr: true,
        });

        await this.container.start();
```

However after connecting this stream to a websocket which is connected to xterm.js, I noticed if I launch a shell like `/bin/sh` through the `cmd` argument and write to the resulting `this.stream`, the commands I run are echoed back to me on the `this.stream.on("data", ...)` listener.

For eg if I write `ls\n`, the data passed into the `.on("data",...)` looks like

```
ls
bin/ etc/ lib/ ... (etc.)
```

How do I prevent it from echoing the "`ls`" back to me?

Here is the code for the stream write and reads on the server:

```js
    let sb = new Sandbox("alpine-sandbox");

    let stream = await sb.launchSHShell();

    stream.on("data", (data) => {
        socket.emit("response", data.toString());
    })

    socket.on("command", (cmd) => {
        stream.write(cmd);
    })
```

Comment: The echo is a feature of the underlying TTY to give ppl feedback of the typed input. It is controlled by the TERMIOS settings and normally not controlled by the terminal side of a TTY, but the application (here: the shell where you typed [`l`, `s`]). Long story short - it is expected to echo things back under normal circumstances - unless the application awaits sensitive data like password input and thus switched echo off on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my current hack to solve this problem is to only read every other `on("data", ...)` response. I noticed that the data listener is called twice, once for the command I wrote and the next for the actual output from the shell. So reading every other response prevents this echo. Still looking for a better solution though.